# Do we need both [asan] and [address-sanitizer]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[asan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asan) [address-sanitizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/address-sanitizer)

They both refer to Google's Address Sanitizer library (`libasan`) and I don't really see any difference. Good to merge?

Comment: What about making address-sanitizer a synonym of asan or vice versa?

Comment: @coldspeed Yes. Merge AND synonymize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked all the 51 questions in the tag and they were all related to the address sanitizer. 15 of them had both the tags. Coincidently, the top users and related tags of both the tags were nearly the same.

I synonymized and merged the tags in this direction [address-sanitizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/address-sanitizer) ← [asan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asan).